# Install Linux without firmware password

Tags: password, unix, firmware, firmware-password

I have a Late 2013 MacBook Pro with an unknown firmware password set. I don't know the firmware password because the laptop is a castoff from a company and I have no way to get the password from them.

I would like to install Linux on it. Is this possible? I would need to cleverly redirect system to boot from an installation USB drive, but I'm afraid of going in blind and bricking the device.

Comment: Try booting into recovery mode by pressing Command+R keys. Go to Utilities screen, access “Firmware Password Utility” and try turning it off.

Comment: Have a look at: [Forgot a Mac Firmware Password? Don’t Panic, Here’s What To Do](http://osxdaily.com/2015/01/28/forgot-mac-firmware-password-what-now/)